# PEX instead of good ol'copper pipe for fresh water in residential house?

Tags: plumbing

New Construction.  Last time I built a house (2001) I used copper water lines through the foundation for eadh location. Now I am told by a plumber that's too old school.  They now use something called PEX where only one fresh water pipe enters the the house through the foundation and the rest is plumbed (hot/cold) through the walls.  Is this a modern solution to weather freezing water lines?  Can I assume it's more expensive?

Comment: Considerably less expensive, actually. Copper prices have gone nuts for some time.

Comment: It's not clear whether you're asking about copper vs. pex or something about the routing of the lines. There's only ever been one line entering the house, regardless of pipe type.

Comment: @isherwood you forget that in Texas the houses are so big that they have separate wells for each end of the house ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is done is because Copper costs tons more money. Otherwise the 'greatness' of it would not be a challenge to copper as copper has antimicrobial properties and is very durable.

The PEX is run through the house to keep it repairable and simple - I do not think there has been any issue with doing this.

I have heard they can run it under the slab for in house water supply. 
They do run PEX in the slab for in SLAB heating.

BTW: I like the OLD SCHOOL Copper - works great in the water supply and it works great for Air Conditioning units, and definitely works great for electricity .. next thing you know the Power Lines in the house will be plastic..

Comment: Yep, nothing like those OLD SCHOOL pinholes when your copper pipe has corroded to the point of not being watertight, too. The OLD SCHOOL burst when frozen behavior is also great. If you are a plumber, anyway...